# Python program question to print even number

Tags: python

I use for loop statement to run the program and it work but when I convert it to while statement it does not work

```
for I in range(1,20):
    If i%2 == 0:
        Print(i)
```

But the conversion does not work with while statement

Comment: Please post actual formatted code, and include your attempt at using a `while` loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You didn't post the code on which you have a question, and the code you *did* post dies for improper capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you try to convert it into while, do you remember that while 
parameter should be an boolean?
if you what to convert your loop to while you should make something like this

```
i=1
while i<=20:
    if i%2 == 0:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

You Canot use an range like 'for' loop

Comment: Yeah, am grateful, I made a mistake by updating it with +=2 whereas it should be +=1

Answer (score 0):

Remember that python is case sensitive, so `i` is not the same as `I`.  Also the built-in function names like `print` are all lower-case.

Which makes your code:

```
for i in range(1,20):
    if i%2 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Converting to a `while()` loop:

```
i=1
while i <= 20:
    if i%2 == 0:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

That should give you a few hints at what to do.